# Android ButtonBar Taking Up All Screen Space

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to implement Bottom Navigation bar using the roughike bottom-bar: https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar

Here is an image of what I get (on my mobile phone):

[image]

I want to keep my toolbar at the top of the device screen. When I run the app, the bottom bar takes up almost all the space of my MainActivity. Does the CoordinatorLayout have to be the parent element for all elements? Here is my XML Layout file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="allblacks.com.ibaleka_android_prototype.MainActivity">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id = "@+id/MainActivityToolbar"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id = "@+id/MainActivityImageView"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/ToolbarTextView"
            android:id = "@+id/MainActivityTextView"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id = "@+id/mainActivityMenu"
        >
        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            >
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id = "@+id/MainActivityContentArea"
                >
            </FrameLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes Coordinator layout need to be the parent layout. [Coordinator Layout Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html) Check the link for getting more details